# All binary converters return 8 digits

Tags: binary

All text to binary converters return a 8 digit per letter code - is there another 0/1 system with less or more digits?

I hear that there are different forms of binary code but all text to binary converters return a 8 digit per letter code (e.x. 01001101).

Is there text to binary conversion which includes only 0 and 1 and does it has less or more number of digits?

If I want to convert text into zeros and ones, will I always end up with 8 digits per letter? Is this 8 digit type of binary conversion used commonly today?

Comment: Well, one byte is 8 bits, why do you expect something different? Unicode characters are actually using two bytes.

Comment: Unicode characters may use anywhere from one to four bytes, depending on the encoding. UTF-8, for example, may use 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. UTF-16 can be two or four bytes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16. And UTF-32 is four bytes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Representing letters as binary requires some kind of standard. Otherwise computers sending bits over a network to each other could never make sense of what letters to turn those bits into!

There are a bunch of standards for character encoding:
[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) and [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings)!

But why are letters (*almost*) always converted to 8-bits?

Before considering letters at all, Binary is just a numeral system with two symbols. You can count up as far as you'd like...
`0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111...`

See how this is similar to the decimal system:
`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13...`

Computers have been designed to store numbers in **bytes**. A byte is always 8-bits long, which means it is possible to store any number from 0 to 255 in one byte.

Now with decimals, you could assign a letter to each number from 1 - 26:
`a=1, b=2, c=3 ... z=26`

In binary you could do the same:
`a=0, b=10, c=11 ... z=11001`

This is where we get into character encoding. [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a very common system for encoding letters as numbers.

In the ASCII standard, you can see that `A=65`, which is `01000001` in binary. Since most computers and software understand ASCII (or [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)), you can be sure that loading a text file with `01000001` in the raw data will result in that character showing up as `A` on any computer.

If you wanted to represent a character in a non-standard way, maybe using 9 bits, you can absolutely do that! But this would mean you are using your own encoding system and other software/computers/people wouldn't be able to convert the binary back to letters without your supporting documentation.